# How to find MCFG table after located RSDP?

Tags: operating-system, bios, acpi

I have located RSDP by searching the valid string.

I know the table contains a pointer direct me to XSDT.

However, I compared the "Length" and the entries in XSDT, only FACP, APIC, SSDT tables are located.

Does this mean that the system does not contain MCFG table?

Therefore I can not using memory map to access PCIe configuration space?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you are facing this problem in QEMU ... adding `-machine q35` flag to the QEMU run command adds the MCFG to the XSDT/RSDT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**MCFG** is not a part of ACPI specification. The table is described in the *PCI Firmware specification* document.

Section 2.7.2 states

> The ACPI MCFG table describes the location of the PCI Express configuration space, and this table will be present in a firmware implementation compliant to this specification version 3.0 (or later).

So, it means your firmware is not compliant to the PCI firmware specification v3.0 or later.

Reading further the section 4.1 about ECAM

> On PC-compatible systems, the enhanced configuration access mechanism allows PCI configuration space to be accessed using memory primitives rather than I/O-based primitives (CF8/CFC mechanism).

So, it means in your case, if you are talking about PC-compatible systems, that only type 1 (CF8/CFC) access to the PCI configuration space is available (you may not reach space beyond 256 bytes).

Of course it may be just a bug in firmware that for some reason *forgot* to describe it. On x86 you may try to access traditional ECAM window (starting from 0xE0000000) and check if it works (be sure the memory region is marked as *reserved* in the OS).

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. So if the MCFG table presents, it should be in XSDT or RSDT right? And the presenting of MCFG table illustrating that I would be able to use memory access to configuration space of PCI devices??

Comment: Yes, this is a requirement to be compliant with the specifications.